# How are missing values computed in R caret package's nearZeroVar function?

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to get better clarity on understanding of behavior of caret::nearZeroVar, when confronted with missing values.

It seems that sometimes, missing values in a column vector are handled as if the function will remove these elements to shorten the vector. But not always.

Some other times, missing values in a column vector are handled as if just some value like any other value. Keep these vector elements.  But not always.

Does function first run zeroVariance check, followed by testing those two thresholds uniqueCut and freqCut?

Can anyone explain correctly how missing values are accounted in function nearZeroVar?

?nearZeroVar was consulted but I am still confused. Thank you. My data have lots of missing values.